# Class Method in 'as_json' not working for index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, methods, rubygems

New to Ruby/Rails, so bear with me.

I have a ActiveRecord model class **Status**.  I'm rendering it as json to be used in a mobile web application. It consists of an **id, name, code, and back_color** (in decimal color).  I needed to do a color conversion from BGR decimal to RGB hex, so I decided to employ the **color** gem.  Ultimately, though, I think the problem fundamental to my method definition.

When I request a single record (`/statuses/1.json`), everything works as expected.  When I ask for the index (`/statuses.json`), I get a Internal Server Error (500).  The most detail I've been able to get from that is an `ArgumentError (ArgumentError)`

I defined the method to do the conversion like so:

```
def color_hex
 bgr = Color::RGB.from_html(back_color.to_s(16)) #converts dec to hex, then creates new color object from it
 rgb = Color::RGB.new(bgr.blue,bgr.green,bgr.red) #swaps red & blue into new color object
 rgb.html #outputs rgb hex for use in html
end
```

I also included a custom `as_json` in the model, adding the `color_hex` method:

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(:methods => :color_hex)
end
```

From my controller, I use the standard `format.json { render :json => @statuses }`.

As I said, I thought it was a fundamental problem, so I simplified the method as a proof of concept: could I at least manipulate the back_color at all?

```
def color_hex
 back_color * -1
end
```

...and it works for both the show and index actions.  As soon as I introduce the color gem in any capacity, it doesn't work.  Again, I'd attribute that to how I'm using the gem, rather than a problem with the gem itself.

What core principle have I neglected to follow?

**TL,DR:** I'm rendering as json, and my custom method is working for the show action, but not the index action.

Comment: Is there more detail in your log/development.log file ? Could it be that one of the statuses in your database has bad data (such that it is no longer valid input for `Color::RGB.from_html`)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'm a but unsure of the etiquette here...  I'd like to mark this as answered, but I don't want to take your "rep" away.  Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that one of the statuses in your database has bad data (such that it is no longer valid input for `Color::RGB.from_html`) ? This would cause the action that loads the entire collection to raise an error but wouldn't cause an issue on most individual ones.

Comment: **facepalm** - it seems so obvious now that you've said it. In fact, it does appear to be a data issue. Trying to load a single instance of the 7th record causes the same problem! I believe additional checks on the data (prior to `Color::RGB.from_html`) will be the resolution here.  Thanks @FrederickCheung!

Answer (score -1):

You just have to rename the as_json method into to_json

```
def to_json(options={})
  super(:methods => :color_hex)
end
```

Comment: Although I've been reading that I should avoid `to_json` in favor of `as_json`, I gave it a shot.  The behavior is the same.  It works for the single (show) action, but not the all (index) action.